# How to manage different content based on a user role in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a structure of different tables in SQL server that allows me to store multiple roles and users (in this case, an User can handle multiple roles).

When I try to turn visible a control in an .aspx depending of the role that the logged-in user has, it gets tired to handle whether to show or not, enable or not the controls that the role should handle.

I already have a solution, but it is hard to maintain. The problem is that the client usually asks for updates from time to time.

What is the best practice to enable controls in .aspx depending on a user role?

An apology for my poor English.

...

...

Every time the client loged-in enter into a .aspx I display different buttons with the roles that he have. For example, if person A have rol 1 and 2 then I display buttons for role 1 and 2. I allow him to choose the role with which he wants to enter the form. If person B have only one rol (for example: rol 3) then I just load the content for rol 3.

```
protected void accesos()
    {
        try
        {
            bool acceso1 = false;   
            bool acceso2 = false;   
            bool acceso3 = false;   
            bool acceso4 = false;   

            int count = 0;
            int intparse = -1;

            if (FL.ValidaAcceso(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["IDSubForma"].ToString()), 3, ((clsUsuario)Session["clsUsuario"]).IDUsuario))
            {
                acceso1 = true;  
                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (FL.ValidaAcceso(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["IDSubForma"].ToString()), 2, ((clsUsuario)Session["clsUsuario"]).IDUsuario))
            {
                acceso2 = true; 
                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (FL.ValidaAcceso(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["IDSubForma"].ToString()), 1, ((clsUsuario)Session["clsUsuario"]).IDUsuario))
            {
                acceso3 = true; 
                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (FL.ValidaAcceso(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["IDSubForma"].ToString()), 4, ((clsUsuario)Session["clsUsuario"]).IDUsuario))
            {
                acceso4 = true; 
                count = count + 1;
            }


            if (count > 1)
            {

                intparse = lblAcceso.Text.Equals("") ? 0 : (Int32.TryParse(lblAcceso.Text, out intparse) ? intparse : 0);
                if (intparse <= 0)
                {
                    //IDENTIFICAR QUE BOTONES MOSTRAR
                    if (acceso1 == false)
                    {
                        wcFirmas.Visible = false;
                        btn1.Visible = false;
                    }
                    if (acceso2 == false)
                    {
                        wcFirmas.Visible = false;
                        btn2.Visible = false;
                    }
                    if (acceso3 == false)
                    {
                        wcFirmas.Visible = false;
                        btn3.Visible = false;
                    }
                    if (acceso4 == false)
                    {
                        wcFirmas.Visible = false;
                        btn4.Visible = false;
                    }


                    divMultipleAcceso.Visible = true;
                    divForma.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            else if (acceso1 == true)  
            {
                lblAcceso.Text = "3";
                divForma.Visible = true;
                cargarForma(txtNoLote);

            }
            else if (acceso2 == true)  
            {
                lblAcceso.Text = "2";
                divForma.Visible = true;
                cargarForma(txtNoLote);

            }
            else if (acceso3 == true)  
            {
                lblAcceso.Text = "1";
                divForma.Visible = true;
                cargarForma(txtNoLote);

            }
            else if (acceso4 == true)  
            {
                lblAcceso.Text = "4";
                divForma.Visible = true;
                cargarForma(txtNoLote);

            }
            else
            {
                divForma.Visible = false;
                Master.MostrarMsn("El usuario no cuenta con privilegios de acceso.", 0);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Master.MostrarMsn(ex.Message, 0); }
    }
```

I save the rol number into a label to compare it in every control of the form to see if I need to display it or not. Then I do something like:

```
if(lblAcceso.Text.Equals("2"))
```

The problem is, if I add an extra rol to this form, (for example, rol 5) then I have to modify the code. The goal is to modify the code as little as possible.

Thanks everyone that have comment so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have code that you can share so we can help find a solution?

Comment: This is a rather broad question with many possible solutions...

Comment: Nobody can advise you on a better solution without seeing what you have just now. Include this code if you want any kind of meaningful answers.

Comment: Also, displaying control depending on a role is one thing, but control is not everything - there is a server-side. Do you check on the server if user can get access to the endpoints where the Controls are pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are configured to use the built in .net role provider
you can do

```
if (this.User.IsInRole("RoleName"))
        {YourControl.Visible = true }
```

or

```
YourControl.Visible = this.User.IsInRole("RoleName")
```

Comment: Take note that  yourc ontrol (YourControl) can be a customized UserControl. As such you can control virtually the entire content of a Page/form

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net role management:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx

```
 if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "ROLENAME"))
    {         
      UsersListBox.Visible = false;
      return;
    }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42(v=vs.110).aspx